# can the scanner class be used to read files off of a different computer through the internet?

Tags: networking, java.util.scanner

I need to be able to read and write .txt files to a folder that is on a server. if it is possible do you have any advice as to how to get started?

Answer (score 0):

[Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) can work with a number of sources, including a File, Sting, and an InputStream.

If the remote computers filesystem was mounted via SMB ("Windows Shares") or NFS or similar, then it could be transparently accessed "as a normal file".

If the remote file is accessible as the response content of an HTTP GET request then `getInputStream` of [HttpURLConnecction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) might be appropriate. (Or, just read the entire response into a String and use that...)

Otherwise, find out how the remote file/resource can be accessed and use that: break down the problem and requirements, come up with a set of solutions, pick the least painful approach, and get to work :-)

Happy coding.